# Is there a method or function for outlining a shape in a binary matrix?

Tags: python, algorithm

Lets say I have the following matrix:

```
 [[0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,1,1,0,0],
  [0,1,1,1,0],
  [0,1,1,1,1]]
```

I would like to plot an outline of the ones in this matrix (essentially a triangle shape) in python. I'm wondering if there is any function that can do this for me or how I would go about doing this.
Edit: I would like to find which elements are on the border and plot a line going around those elements. Here is what I have for determining if an element is on the border:

```
def check_border(A,i,j):
    if A[i][j] == 0:
        print("false")
        return False

    elif i == 0: #check if element is on the top border
        print("i")
        return True
    elif j == 0:#check if the element is on the left side
        print('j')
        return True
    elif i == (len(A)-1):#check if element is on the bottom border
        print('k')
        return True
    elif j == (len(A[0])-1):#check if element is on the right side
        print('p')
        return True
    elif A[i+1][j] == 0 or A[i-1][j] == 0 or A[i][j+1] == 0 or A[i][j-1] == 0: # check if the one has a neibour that is a zero
        print('q')
        return True
```

For whatever reason, this runs but not correctly and I cant figure out why.

Comment: Can you think of a rule that tells you, for a given `1` value in the matrix, based on looking at the adjacent values, whether or not it is inside or on the border of the shape?

Comment: just treat it as a tile map where 1 is white and 0 is black or something

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks, that makes sense. I can just run a bunch of if statements in a function and call that when I loop through the matrix. Heres some code that I made, but I keep getting an error about the indexes being out of bounds. ``````

Comment: ^ I updated the question with the code

Answer (score 1):

maybe this?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
out = Image.new("RGB", (150, 100), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(out)
cell_sz = 10
a = [[0,1,0,0,0],
  [0,1,1,0,0],
  [0,1,1,1,0],
  [0,1,1,1,1]]
for y,row in enumerate(a):
    for x,v in enumerate(row):
        tl=x*cell_sz,y*cell_sz
        br=tl[0]+cell_sz,tl[1]+cell_sz
        color = [0xFFFFFF,0x0][v]
        draw.rectangle([tl,br],color)

out.save("new.jpg")
```

[image]